# Java NMS method return NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, minecraft

(sorry for my bad english I'm from France).

I am making a bukkit plugin which serialize somme items. I use the native serialization system (implements Serializable ...). Then I've made a class Named SerializableItemStack (source below).

```
public static SerializableItemStack fromItemStack(ItemStack stack) {
    try {
        net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ItemStack cis = CraftItemStack
                .asNMSCopy(stack);
        if (stack == null) {
            System.out.println("Stack is null");
            return null;
        }
        if (cis == null) {
            System.out.println("Cis is null");
            return null;
        }

        SerializableNBTTagCompound nbt = null;
        if (cis.hasTag()) {
            nbt = SerializableNBTTagCompound.fromNBTTagCompound(cis.tag);
        }
        return new SerializableItemStack(stack.getType().name(),
                stack.getDurability(), stack.getAmount(), nbt,
                stack.getItemMeta());
    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that the method CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy return null. I don't know why.

**Output**

```
Cis is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Wolf-in-a-bukkit/Craftbukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/inventory/CraftItemStack.java#L27) of `CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy` there are several possibilities - depending on the passed stack object - why it returns null, even if the stack object is not null.

So either the returned null is OK, or you have to sanitize the stack object, if you really need a non-null return value.

Comment: I suppose that satanize mean show informations about the stack ?
`type: COOKED_BEEF
Amount: 52
Durability: 0
Has no enchants
Has no display name
Has no lores`

Comment: @Sam54 with sanitize I meant the following: if you really require that `asNMSCopy(stack)` returns not null you could throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it does, to signal to the caller that the stack object cannot be serialized. But this depends on the semantics of your code

Comment: Ok. I found the problem.
The class CraftItemStack request the server id list and use it to convert the item as an nms item. The method returned null because I am using the method in a script. But the script don't launch the server. I must use it as a server plugin :).